# Swift: How to add friendships to an app with parse?

Tags: xcode, parsing, swift, request, friend

How do I enable a user to send a friend request to another user. Let him accept or deny it. Eventually display a friend list with all users who accepted the request.

I am working on an iOS app in swift, with a Parse backend. I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks